# How to negotiate job offer based on health condition

Tags: interviewing, health

I'm interviewing at a new company and the process seems to be going well so far.  They're interviewing for a position in office Location A, but I know that their Downtown Location B, 10 minutes away from Location A, will be in an environment that is much safer for my physical health.  I want to ask for opportunities to work from location B, with the following goals in mind:

- I want to express how important Downtown Location B could be for me and how much I'd be willing to negotiate to find a solution that lets me work from B
- I don't want to bring up health in a way that is legally problematic for the hiring manager/recruiter
- I would ultimately be willing to accept an offer for Location A, so I don't want to unnecessarily damage my chances of a job offer overall

I have a video screen and an in-person interview upcoming.

To elaborate, I'm sensitive to heat such that I will get sick if I'm not in a climate-controlled environment.  I don't have an official doctor's note right now.  Being too warm one day is very uncomfortable, but manageable.  Being warm chronically over the summer, say from the walk between a parking lot and the office, causes complications that are difficult to treat and potentially dangerous.

Downtown Location B has a same-building apartment and other amenities that would allow me to remain indoors through the summer as needed.  Even Location A is in a city with a much cooler climate than my current city, so I'm eager to make a move.  Of course, I'd vastly prefer Downtown Location B, and would be willing to take a salary cut, take on extra hours, or commute to Location A during the cool half of the year if that's what it took to be placed in B.

How can I address my desire for the Downtown Location B in my job negotiations?  How can I (sincerely) pass it off as something that is valuable to me and will generate loyalty?  And do I need to speak with HR before - or even instead of - any manager who can make those decisions?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you in the US? If so, the ADA requires employers to make reasonable accommodations for any employee requiring them. However, you'd probably need some kind of diagnosis from a doctor.

Comment: I think this might fall under the category of 'do you have any questions you would like to ask us?' questions in the interview. "would there be any opportunities to work from location B?"

Comment: Is it possible for you to get a handicap placard for your car so you don't have to walk as far? That might be useful to you in general, regardless of how this pans out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I address my desire for the Downtown Location B in my job
>   negotiations?

You should ask if it is possible to work in Downtown Location B during your very first interview.

Some jobs can be accomplished anywhere, others cannot. Some companies will be flexible with your location, others cannot.

If they say it's not possible, then you need to decide if your health is more important than the job, or not. If the former, then thank them for their interest and find a different job and company. Since you write "Being warm chronically over the summer, say from the walk between a parking lot and the office, causes complications that are difficult to treat and potentially dangerous." I would assume that you are better served by finding a different job is Downtown Location B is not available.

If they ask you why you prefer Downtown Location B, then you can expound on your health issues. Sometimes that would matter to the employer, sometimes it won't and they would still need the position filled in Location A. If they like you, they may offer to put you on a list for when a position in Downtown Location B becomes available down the road.